# Playframework 2.3 application.conf configuration substitution

Tags: playframework, substitution, hocon

In application.conf I added the following properties

```
property1="value1"
property2="prefix ${property1}"
```

In any controller I added the following code

```
  println(Play.application.configuration.underlying.getString("property1"))
  println(Play.application.configuration.underlying.getString("property2"))
  println(Play.application.configuration.getString("property1"))
  println(Play.application.configuration.getString("property2"))
```

The output is

```
value1
prefix ${property1}
Some(value1)
Some(prefix ${property1})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the property2 is not substituted since is quoted.

Use

```
property1="value1"
property2=prefix ${property1}
```

See [unquoted string](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#unquoted-strings) section.